# Playwright tests with Next-Auth not picking up session token in cookie

Tags: javascript, playwright, next-auth

Goal: Use playwright for testing without having to log in multiple times as per documentation [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth).

Problem: Playwright tests not picking up session token from Next-Auth and hence am not able to reuse an authenticated status across mutiple tests.

My understanding is that Next-Auth checks for `next-auth.session-token` to validate the auth status. However following the above docs, I've noticed that the session token never get's stored in  the `storageState.json`. If I manually add in the session token to the JSON then the tests work as expected.

[Here](https://github.com/JustTro11/next-auth-playwright) is a very barebones repo I've setup with just a login button and one test.

Here's the typical `[...nextAuth].js`

```
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: true,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Here's the `global-setup.js` for Playwright with email/password swapped out

```
module.exports = async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in with GitHub' }).click();
  await page
    .getByLabel('Username or email address')
    .fill('email');
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();

  await page.context().storageState({ path: 'storageState.json' });
  await browser.close();
};
```

Here's the e2e test I'm running

```
const { test, expect } = require("@playwright/test");

test.use({
  storageState: "storageState.json",
});

test("sign in through github", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:3000");
  await expect(page.getByText("Signed in as")).not.toBeEmpty();
});
```

I expect the auth state to be stored in `storageState.json` from the code in `global-setup.js`. It does indeed store information there but it's missing the `next-auth.session-token` for some reason and hence causes the tests I'm running to fail.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? One thought is that maybe the global setup didn’t wait long enough after clicking the sign in button before saving the storageState.

Comment: No never solved it. The global setup stores stuff, it just for some reason leaves out the "next-auth.session-token". I'll probably try my luck creating a ticket in playwright's github page. Interesting to see no one else is having a similar issue nor are there examples online.

Comment: That is odd… if you add a breakpoint/pause, run in debug mode, and inspect the browser are you able to find that cookie? Just to make sure the cookie is there and that Playwright is just not saving it. Could also potentially use [Playwright’s cookies method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-cookies) to see if Playwright can find it that way to determine if Playwright even detects the cookie, if that makes sense.

Comment: Verified that the cookie is there, that's why I posted the question in the first place. I'll look into the cookies method you suggested, thanks.

Comment: You stated that your “understanding is that Next-Auth checks for” it, and that it wasn’t in the storageState.json, but never indicated that you had verified the cookie was actually there when it runs and could’ve just assumed it would’ve been there, or that it would’ve been there at the time storageState.json was saved, so I wanted to clarify/confirm. I am interested in the potential results of using the cookies method to try and check what Playwright sees, as it could point more specifically to the issue.

Comment: Yeah, having the same trouble trying out this implementation https://github.com/juliusmarminge/t3-complete/tree/main/e2e . My global setup method runs but the cookies are never stored :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

In `playwright.config.ts`, in the projects section, I added a path to the storage state file (where `user.js` is located):

```
projects: [
   { name: 'auth-setup', testMatch: /auth\.setup\.ts/ },
   {
     name: 'Desktop Chrome',
     use: {
       ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
       storageState: <storage_state_path>, // <---- Add this
     },
     dependencies: ['auth-setup'],
   },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the mentioned **next-auth.session-token** is stored but it does not happen instantly with other cookies at start.

In my situation waiting for url helped.

So:

1. Login as user
2. Check session cookies - **next-auth.session-token** will not be there yet
3. Wait for some url with **page.waitForUrl()** so that the page would load
4. Check session cookies - the **next-auth.session-token** should be there (it was in my case)